# Constraining a routing namespace to JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes

I am a little bit confused by the numerous ways to constrain a routing namespace to a format. I'd like to know what the differences between the different approaches are:

1. Set the `format` option as in:

   ```
    namespace :api, format: 'json'
   ```

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources):

> **:format**
>
> Allows you to specify the default value for optional format segment or disable it by supplying false.

Is this the same as having a `before_action` in a controller:

```
before_action :set_format

def set_format
  reqeust.format ||= :json
end
```

?

2. Set the format in the `defaults` hash:

   ```
    namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' }
   ```
3. Set the format in the `constraints` hash:

   ```
    namespace :api, constraints: { format: 'json' }
   ```

However, according to the second note of section [Request-Based Constraints](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) from the Rails guides:

> There is an exception for the format constraint: while it's a method on the Request object, it's also an implicit optional parameter on every path. Segment constraints take precedence and the format constraint is only applied as such when enforced through a hash. For example, get 'foo', constraints: { format: 'json' } will match GET  /foo because the format is optional by default. However, you can use a lambda like in get 'foo', constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :json } and the route will only match explicit JSON requests.

which leads to:

4. Set the format explicitly in a lambda:

   ```
    namespace :api, constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :json }
   ```

Can somebody explain the subtle differences in these four approaches?

Thank you.

Comment: the thing that makes it a bit confusing is that `format` is optional. so if you really want to enforce all requests to be queried with an accept-header of application/json, i guess the last method is the one that would do that.